# Datastore transaction - hitting entity write limit

Tags: go, transactions, datastore

#### The Problem

Using the golang `cloud.google.com/go/datastore` package to create a transaction, perform a series of `getMulti`'s, and `putMulti`'s, on commit of this transaction I'm confronted with an an entity write limit error.

```
2021/12/22 09:07:18 err: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = cannot write more than 500 entities in a single call
```

#### The Question

**My question is how do you create a transaction with more than 500 writes?**

While I *want* my operation to remain atomic, I can't seem to solve this write limit error for a transaction and the set of queries run just fine when I test on an emulator, writing in batches of 500.

#### What I've Tried

please excuse the sudo code but I'm trying to get the jist of what I've done
All in one

```
    transaction, err := datastoreClient.NewTransaction(ctx)
    transaction.PutMulti(allKeys, allEntities)
    transaction.commit()
// err too many entities written in a single call
```

Batched in an attempt to avoid the write limit

```
    transaction, err := datastoreClient.NewTransaction(ctx)
    transaction.PutMulti(first500Keys, first500Entities)
    transaction.PutMulti(second500Keys, second500Entities)
    transaction.commit()
// err too many entities written in a single call
```

A simple regular putmulti also fails

```
    datastoreClient.PutMulti(ctx,allKeys, allEntities)
// err too many entities written in a single call
```

#### What Works

Non-atomic write to the datastore

```
    datastoreClient.PutMulti(ctx,first500Keys, first500Entities)
    datastoreClient.PutMulti(ctx,second500Keys, second500Entities)
```

here's the real code that I used for the write, either as a  batched transaction or regular putMulti

```
    for i := 0; i < (len(allKeys) / 500); i++ {
        var max int = (i + 1) * 500
        if len(allKeys) < max {
            max = len(allKeys) % 500
        }

        _, err = svc.dsClient.PutMulti(ctx, allKeys[i*500:max], allEntities[i*500:max])
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
    }
```

#### Where I'm Lost

so in an effort to keeping my work atomic, is there any method to commit a transaction that has more than 500 entities written in it?

Comment: Don't use Google Datastore, it's got some serious design flaws. Apart from being a royal vendor lock-it, for example it can't skip unknown columns. Which means one can't safely add a new column without all existing clients breaking immediately.

Comment: @rustyx Hind sight tends to be 20/20 :) I'm inheriting the work so the choice isn't and wasn't mine but we have our sights set on transitioning to a different storage solution eventually!

Comment: If you ever decide to move away from DS [here's](https://github.com/rustyx/dsutil) a nice DS data backup/export tool. It helped us move from DS to postgres.

Comment: very cool, thanks! We're in the process of doing just that for a portion of our product. though I'm not doing it myself. I'll forward the link to the dev doing the migration and see if he can get some use out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing you can do. This limit is enforced by the platform to ensure scalability and to prevent performance degradation. You can't write more than 500 entities in a single transaction.

It's possible to change the limit on *Google's* side, but nothing you can do on *your* side.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was hoping that this would not be the case but was the conclusion I was coming to. some of the things I found online were confusing, like 500 writes per-second, so I didn't even expect my batched, non-transaction puts to necessarily work.